# Installing desktop in Ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: 14.04

I installed Ubuntu desktop and lubuntu desktop on ubuntu server like this:

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

But it didn't install basic programs like terminal and I dont see any applets on the topbar when new programs are installed (like teamviewer), I also install virtual box but when I try to run by searching its not there..

Totally confused. I would like to user this server as I would use a fully fledged ubuntu desktop. unfortunately reinstalling from scratch is not option for me right now.

Comment: Do you mean "ubuntu" or "lubuntu"? You have stated each at separate times in your question, but they are distinctly different desktops.

Comment: both have been installed seperate, problems happen in both of them even after reinstalling them with --install-recommends

Answer (score 7):

You want the recommended packages for ubuntu-desktop .

```
sudo apt-get --install-recommends install ubuntu-desktop
```

Or else if that doesn't work due to ubuntu-desktop already being installed...

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get --install-recommends install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't make any difference to my problem, but it did install office programs and other things that comes with ubuntu desktop, still no terminal or any way for me to search for installed programs.... weird.

Comment: There is no button for searching at the top of the Unity panel?

Comment: @MGodby I read somewhere "if you're using it as a real "Server" (ftp, web hosting, DNS, etc.), it is highly recommended to learn how to navigate Ubuntu via its shell instead of the GUI. There are packages that install GUIs for different server functions." ---- Do you know any solution?!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde do you mean a way to do your server administration from GUIs instead? Or do you mean for managing server functions while still having the GUI up? The latter just requires you to open a terminal emulator.

Comment: @MGodby I installed Ubuntu server (No GUI). And now want to have GUI on it. With fewest changes on server stuff.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde You should be set to just install the gui packages you want. It shouldn't affect your server applications. The person in that article most likely meant which manner you manage your applications, not whether or not a gui is present. Just make sure you have a terminal emulator installed and use that to manage your server apps. I personally like terminator and Ubuntu's default terminal emulator a lot.